# TypeScript: Ability to infer/derive values for type from const object literal, nested with non-unique keys

Tags: typescript

I have a style guide object that I would like to be able to use TS/IDE to see specific literal values from, instead of inferred type. For example:

```
const guide = {
  colors: {
    black: {
      medium: "#000000",
    },
    blue: {
      medium: "#3884F7",
      dark: "#053986",
    }
...
  },
  typography: {
    font: {
      family: "Commissioner",
      size: {
        xxs: "11px",
        xs: "12px",
        s: "14px"
...
    },
  },
};
```

Is there a way to have (for example) `guide.colors.blue.dark` typed as `"#053986"` rather than `string` without remapping the entire object to a type object (or objects) manually.

Comment: just add `as const` after the object literal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) to tell the compiler to infer the most specific type it can from an object initializer, including the [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) of its property and subproperty values:

```
const guide = {
  colors: {
    black: {
      medium: "#000000",
    },
    blue: {
      medium: "#3884F7",
      dark: "#053986",
    }

  },
  typography: {
    font: {
      family: "Commissioner",
      size: {
        xxs: "11px",
        xs: "12px",
        s: "14px"

      },
    },
  }
} as const; // <-- const assertion
```

which produces

```
/* const guide: {
    readonly colors: {
        readonly black: {
            readonly medium: "#000000";
        };
        readonly blue: {
            readonly medium: "#3884F7";
            readonly dark: "#053986";
        };
    };
    readonly typography: {
        readonly font: {
            readonly family: "Commissioner";
            readonly size: {
                readonly xxs: "11px";
                readonly xs: "12px";
                readonly s: "14px";
            };
        };
    };
} */
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true#code/MYewdgzgLgBA5gVwJYBMCmMC8MDeAoGGUAGxACcIAuXAwmAI2IENgBra-OugWzRSQTdqAIgDEABklThAGlqEAvnK6MEaDvJ58BQmGIDMADkMAWAGIB2WZsIomZdnokBWfQE5DANmtcFeWkq0UACeAA4gcGRMoQAWwRpcAGbgUAlcMIlM3EjE8XoAwiDc2RAQSOBoZD7pZQBe6jTpdAAezVR6AIwdoc3VTW0iHQBMPX01gyaj-k2BvsowfgowTBBE4NAA3P4A9ABUa5CwiKgNnHRkaEwo4LlrpBRpTRdXN8EMzGyPTeeX12C3vH4ghEEikkmEW2+C0h32ef1uqlONlhv1eMEBOhBRlMlghyKeqP+bzsDhB4lcHm8MJm1OhmjhaJC4Ui0TiXy4DKJGRS7JRLy5mWyuREhWKSFK5TAlTxUI5hNudSRsr58LerXawi6o1pysInNuA06I16Ot1+reGo6kxN+PSClNilp9rwS122yAA)